# Flask-WTF library gives a "The CSRF session token is missing" error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement CSRF tokens in my flask backend. I have created a route to create and get a CSRF token. This route works fine and it sends back the required CSRF token, but when i try to use this token within the header of my post request to /login I get the error "The CSRF session token is missing". Here is my python code I am using flask-wtf version 1.1.1

```
import jwt
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf

# Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "simple"
cache = Cache(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc'
CORS(app, origins=['http://localhost:4200'], supports_credentials=True)

class controller:
    @app.route('/api/csrf_token', methods=['GET'])
    @csrf.exempt  # Exclude CSRF protection for this route
    def get_csrf_token():
        csrf_token = generate_csrf()
        print(csrf_token)
        return jsonify({'csrf_token': csrf_token})

    @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def check_login():
        loginCredentials = request.get_json()
        return jsonify({'success': False})
```

Here is how I tried to send a post request in postman.
[image: Here is how I tried to send a post request in postman]

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that what is missing is the 'csrf_token' entry in the session object. Could it be that your session have been somehow corrupted?

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Please avoid the impression to ask a question instead of answering. You can e.g. phrase a conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is ... because ... ."